# The correct way to embedd a bash script into another bash script

Tags: shell-script, shell

Please suggest or correct the following code or make it simpler if possible.

The file must be a embedded inside the single shell script file.

**`Embedded.sh`**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo '#!/bin/bash
read input
while [[ $input -eq Y ]]; do echo hi ; done ' > /tmp/test.sh
chmod ugo+w /tmp/test.sh ; chmod ugo+w /tmp/test.sh ; chmod ugo+x /tmp/test.sh
konsole -e sh /tmp/test.sh
rm /tmp/test.sh
```

Comment: This really smells like an XY problem. What is the goal you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm just trying to run a shell script without entering terminal on single Click it should launch the script inside the terminal. All because of `konosole` in KDE plasma don't support multiple commands and can't run a shell script without entering to the terminal

Comment: Note that it's not necessary to make the script executable or writable if you're executing it like `sh file`, it just needs to be readable

Comment: ... and, if you want it to be run in bash (i.e., as a bash script), you should say `bash /tmp/test.sh` instead of `sh /tmp/test.sh`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

out=/tmp/script.sh

data='
IyEvYmluL2Jhc2gKcmVhZCBpbnB1dAp3aGlsZSBbWyBcJGlucHV0IC1lcSBZIF1dOyBkbyAj
IG5vdGUgdGhlIGVzY2FwZWQgJCBoZXJlCiAgZWNobyBoaQpkb25lCg=='

base64 -d <<<"$data" >"$out" &&
chmod +x "$out"
```

Encode the contained script.  Here I'm using base64 encoding. For larger scripts, compress the data with `gzip` before encoding it with `base64`, then decompress it after decoding it with `base64 -d <<<"$data" | gzip -cd >"$out"`.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly more readable would be a heredoc:

```
#!/bin/bash
tempscript="$(mktemp)"
trap 'rm "$tempscript"' EXIT
cat > "$tempscript" << EOF
#!/bin/bash
read input
while [[ \$input -eq Y ]]; do # note the escaped $ here
  echo hi
done
EOF
chmod u+x "$tempscript"
"$tempscript"
```

Comment: It's not that clear what the OP is trying to achieve, but I gather the only reason to create a separate script rather than just executing the code directly would be so that it can be run in konsole (or a new konsole instance). Your answer doesn't use konsole at all.

Comment: Use a quoted heredoc to avoid having to escape anything

Comment: I use the last line like this after the answer `konsole -e /tmp/script.sh ; rm /tmp/script.sh`

Comment: This script I want to make it simpler and directly run inside the `konsole` [GitHub Script](https://github.com/hackdev17/smi2latex/blob/main/smi2latex.sh)